# How to access a member variable from a python static method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Settings:
    WORKSPACE = env.get("BK_WKPS")

    def localize_path(*args):
        if WORKSPACE["path"]:
            path = join_path(WORKSPACE["path"], *args)
            return path
        else:
            return None

    log_location = localize_path("logs")

print(Settings.log_location)
```

> File settings.py",
>
> line 27, in localize_path
>
> if WORKSPACE["path"]:
>
> NameError: name 'WORKSPACE' is not defined

Comment: Looks like this shouldn’t be a class at all.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Settings' is not defined`

Comment: Note, `log_location` is also a member. I know code is wrong, as both member variable will be evaluated before the method call, but how would you code this workspace.

Comment: Why `def localize_path` at all? Just `log_location = WORKSPACE['path'] and join_path(...)` would do.

Comment: for external usecases

Comment: That's *not* a static method, it's an instance method, and if it needs access to class attributes it should be a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `log_location` member is being initialised before the class has been defined, so I think you should pass `WORKSPACE` in as a parameter:

```
class Settings:
    WORKSPACE = env.get("BK_WKPS")

    def localize_path(WS, *args):
        if WS["path"]:
            path = join_path(WS["path"], *args)
            return path
        else:
            return None

    log_location = localize_path(WORKSPACE, "logs")

print(Settings.log_location)
```

**Update:**

I'm sure this is bad form, using a method like this, because you are leaving behind a class with a method that another programmer will think that they can call.